# iOS 16 Orientation issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, orientation, ios16

I have an issue with iOS 16 for some views:
My app is only in landscape orientation, but I have 2 views in portrait orientation, in previous iOS versions all works good, but now I found case with 2 different views when I go to view and hold my phone in portrait orientation -> viewDidload I saw in landscape, viewDidAppear in portrait too, then app calls setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations() and screen rotate to portrait orientation
I can't catch what method rotate screen

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        let presentedViewController = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController
        if presentedViewController is UIImagePickerController {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight.rawValue)
        }
        if presentedViewController is ChatPhotoPageContainerViewController {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all.rawValue)
        }
        return .landscape
    }
```

Tried to call in viewController `

```
windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscape))
```

`but it doesn't help, tried override vars`supportedInterfaceOrientations`and`preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` doesn't help too